# PHP Array sort by number of repeats

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array with non-unique values, I need the array to be unique and ordered by the number of times each value returns.

I have got to place where I have an array with every unique value and the number of times that this value repeated - problem is, I need the array ordered with the values when the most repeated is first and the lowest repeated at last. (used array_count_values)

The array has a lot of results to handle..

un-ordered array:

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(4)
  [3]=>
  int(2)
  [4]=>
  int(3)
  [5]=>
  int(4)
  [6]=>
  int(5)
  [7]=>
  int(1)
  [8]=>
  int(2)
  [9]=>
  int(3)
  [10]=>
  int(4)
  [11]=>
  int(1)
  [12]=>
  int(2)
  [13]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Ordered array (value refers to repeats):

```
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [5]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: Is that bottom array supposed to go 3, 4, 3, 3, 1?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of your problem, wouldn't just `asort()` fix the `array_count_values()` array?

Comment: Correct. it's just array_count_values and asort:

$freqs = array_count_values($array); 

asort($freqs);

Comment: Becuase I need to sort the array by number of repeats, but in the same time I need to work with the ids that saved in the value.